# Windows Phone Profiler don't work in project with multiple assemblies and pcl

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with the Windows phone application analysis tool in VS 2012, 
when I start any of the three available profiling modes on my project with multiple assemblies, the project is being rebuilt and nothing happens, only the progress ring is animating and I can't exit VS without killing its process in Task Manager, but when I run it on a sample project with only the one app project the profiler runs perfectly. 
I don't know where the problem is, so please if anyone had this problem too, share your solution for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one image named with non ASCII characters and renaming it solved the problem.